# construction usage of "– of the + noun"

Tags: meaning-in-context, definite-article

I'm confused by the construction of "of the noun" in a sentence. I always think that "of" means "in" and "the" means "this". Is my understanding right? "Of the noun" means "in this noun". Or "Of the" may mean "during this". This structure is often seen in sentences as in ... of the day/the week/the afternoon, etc.

- Anthony Gordon's first shot **of the match** came in the 55th minutes.
- Manchester United make their first substitute **of the game**.
- Word **of the day**.
- Who is tonight's **player of the match**?
- That was the best goal
  **of the afternoon**.

So I interpret "of the" in the examples above as:

- Anthony Gordon's first shot of the match came in the 55th minutes. = Anthony Gordon's first shot **in this match** came in the 55th minutes.
- Manchester United make their first substitute of the game. = Man Utd make their first substitute **in this game**.
- Word of the day. = Word **in this day**.
- Who is tonight's player of the match? = Who is tonight's player **in this match**.
- That was the best goal of the afternoon. = That was the best goal **in this afternoon**.

Can I substitute "of the" for "in this?"

- Word in this day.
- Who is the player in this match?
- Anthony Gordon's first shot in this match came in the 55th minutes
- That was the best goal in this afternoon.

Comment: In a restaurant, the 'soup of the day' is the type of soup that the cook has chosen to make today. The 'word of the day' is an interesting word that a newspaper or website has chosen to feature today.

Comment: @KateBunting Could you explain when to use the construction of "–of the"? I always use "in this". Word in this day.  A first change in this afternoon for Man Utd.

Comment: _Word in this day_ doesn't mean anything in English. The expression for something chosen for a particular day is "X of the day". _Of the_ can be used in other contexts, as Tim explains in his answer.

Comment: @KateBunting Could I say "today's word of the day?"

Comment: You could, although strictly speaking 'today's' is unnecessary, because 'X of the day' implies today unless another day is specified - "Yesterday's soup of the day was tomato".

Comment: @KateBunting What does "of the" mean in this sentence? *We're underway in **the second game of the night*** and it's been a lively start*.

Comment: "The second game scheduled to take place this evening".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150203/discussion-between-nyambek-and-kate-bunting).

Comment: @KateBunting In this context, *of* doesn't mean belong to, doesn't it? The second game belongs to this evening.

Comment: You didn't post anything in chat (but I have done so).

Comment: @KateBunting - in my UK Civil Service canteen, they used to have fish and chips on Fridays, and on the printed menus that were put up around the building, it was called 'Fresh Caught Catch of the Day'. That was a blatant lie.

Comment: @KateBunting I have posted there. But the "of the + noun" structure has a sense of ***in this***, hasn't it? As in "... of the afternoon/of the season". This means in this afternoon and in this season.

Comment: You cannot have more than one 55th minute. There's only one 55th minute IN a football game, so making "minute" plural IN the phrase 55th minutes" is  ungrammatical.

Answer (score 2):

1. Beware about replacing "the" with "this." It "sort of" works. But: "*Time* magazine's '**Person of the Year**' for 2006 was 'You.'" Obviously, 2006 is not the present year. But the definite article "the" means "THE thing we're specifically discussing," and "this" can have some of that sense as well, so as long as we're clear that "this year means 2006," then you could make the substitution I guess. Or better yet, if you're clear on what "the" means, just let "the" be "the."
2. "Of" is such a multi-purpose word that it can fill many roles. If you really want to replace it with something, maybe the best replacement is "*relating to or having to do with*." This is cumbersome, but fills all the distinctions between "in the," "for the," "belonging to the," etc. Because this really is the "universal" meaning of "of", and then context helps us narrow our understanding into a more specific meaning.

Comment: Does "of" mean "relating to" in this sentence? And "the" means "this". Anthony Gordon's first shot **of the match** came in the 55th minutes.

Comment: @Nyambek Meaning is created by context. You *could say* that that means "first shot having to do with the match." That's an awkward construction that nobody would actually say, and "first shot *in* the match" would be a much more comfortable replacement. But yes, it *is* a "shot that in some way has something to do with the match," and that's the meaning of "of" that covers *all* its uses (at least, all that I can think of). As I said above, the context then helps us create a narrower meaning out of that broad meaning.

Comment: @Nyambek To be clear: you can never really say "word X means Y." Maybe it does in a certain context; it might have another in other contexts.

Comment: Thanks Andy. Could you explain how "would" works in your sentence? ... and first shot *in* the match" **would be** a much more comfortable replacement.

Comment: @Nyambek Hm, just as normal, I guess. I'm not sure how it would be confusing; maybe that could be a new question of its own? (Accompanied by evidence that you've looked "would" up in a dictionary and know about conditional mood, but I think you do.)

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Could you explain your use of "would" in your sentence? I'm not sure how it **would be** confusing;

Comment: @Nyambek Sorry, conditionals are a big topic, and comments aren't really the place for it. Maybe [start here](https://blog.lillypad.ai/grammar/verbs/conditional-mood/)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150225/discussion-between-nyambek-and-andy-bonner).

Answer (score 0):

"Of" can have different meanings, so "of the/this" cannot always be replaced with "in the/this".

"Word in this day" is incorrect as "of" in the original means "assigned to". "in this day" means during the day, which is very different. Check the many definitions of "of" in Chambers.

"Player of the match" is a specific phrase meaning the player (chosen somehow) as the best in the particular match. You could say "he was the best player in/of the/this match" but that would just be expressing an opinion. "the player of the match" implies an actual award.

"Anthony Gordon's first shot in this match came in the 55th minutes" is a correct alternative to the original "of the". Here "of the" uses "of" to mean during and "the" is a synonym for "this" as it refers to the match currently being talked about. The two are equally valid in both versions (of or in).

"That was the best goal in this afternoon" is wrong. "in the afternoon" would be grammatically correct but not as good as "of the". It would also have the possibility of meaning in all games that afternoon, although that would be ambiguous.

Comment: So "the" is used to refer to an event currently being talk about, isn"t it? I'm watching a football macth, then I can say "Liverpool make their first change of the afternoon". "Of the afternoon" mean in this affernoon, doesn't it? Or during this afternoon.

Comment: "the" means a specific thing whcih would be the thing already introduced if there is one, as in this context. "Liverpool make their first change of the afternoon", refers to this afternoon. "of" = "during", although "during" would not be idiomatic in this context.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Does "of the day" mean in this day?

Comment: @Nyambek No, it does not mean "in this day" which is not used in English. "x of the day" refers to whatever **date** the x was important on.